# AssemblyResolve Event Handler vs. CodeBase policies

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, assemblyresolve

When trying to access assemblies from a C# assembly, there are several methods:

1. Implement a `AssemblyResolve` event handler
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx
2. Use the  property in the .config file to redirect assembly requests

As stated in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resolveeventargs.name(v=vs.110).aspx for the property of ResolveEventArgs of the event in (1): "Name is the assembly name before policy is applied."

However, I couldn't find any documentation about the order of these methods.
Is the `AssemblyResolve` event handler called before the redirects are probed? Or the other way around?

Second, is there a possibility to somehow apply the policy to the `ResolveEventArgs`? For example to request the redirected version range from the .config file?

Comment: It is fired when the CLR cannot find the assembly.  So after probing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two questions here. Correct me if I'm no providing enough information.

1. `AssermblyResolve` event is invoked only if loader doesn't manage to find assembly it is looking for. So, first assembly load locations are probed, and then if assembly is not found, `AssermblyResolve` event is invoked. If all assemblies are loaded correctly, `AssemblyResolve` event will not fire at all.
2. It is possible to load assembly manually to default `AppDomain` if that is what you mean. When assembly doesn't load correctly, and `AssemblyResolve` of the `AppDomain` fires, you have a chance to resolve it manually.

First you attach to the event to get informed that loading an assembly has failed

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
```

And then try to load replacement assembly from a different place, depending on your criteria:

```
static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name == "ClassLibrary1, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e261024fcc198a53")
        return Assembly.LoadFile("d:\\differentPath\\ClassLibrary1.dll");
    else
        return null;
}
```

Binding redirects as far as I know are useful for redirecting to a different version of assembly, but not redirecting loader to specific path where to look for assemblies.

Comment: Your are totally correct. However, MSDN seems to be a bit wrong. If I use binding redirects to redirect to a different version, the AssemblyResolve Handler is called with the redirected version, not the original one. (That actually suits me quite well though)